# Как настроить ширину input в форме с bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="register-form" role="form" action="/auth/register/" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">            
                   <div class="control-group required">            
                        <label class="control-label" for="id_username">Имя пользователя</label>
                   <div class="controls">     
                   <input class="form-control" id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />                  
                </div> 
               <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" class="button" value="Зарегистрироваться"/>                
    </form>
</div>
```

Форма отображается красиво, input-ы с закруглениями, тенями и т.п. 
Благодаря классу `.form-control`, однако в официальной документации написано:

> All textual input, textarea, and select elements with
>   .form-control are set to width: 100%; by default.

Все остальное в форме устраивает.
Нашел [способ с колонками](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_sizing.asp)
Если к `div` с классом `control-group` я добавляю, например, класс `col-xs-3`, его ширина меняется, однако все поля выстраиваются в горизонтальную линию [как здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_input_width&stacked=h)
Но мне нужна вертикальная форма с полями не на 100% ширины, как ее сделать, сохранив остальные свойства оформления из класса `.form-control`?

Comment: @Alex к сожалению, проблема пока не решена. В Вашем примере кнопка и поле ввода имеют одинаковую ширину. Причем кнопка по верстке вылезает за инпут. Необходимо оформление аналогично тому, что в примере https://jsfiddle.net/384n7njn/1/ т.е. ширина кнопки не равняется ширине инпутов. Однако общая ширина формы не должна быть 100% от ширины страницы.

Comment: @Alex  100% инпут не нужен. Проблема изначально в том, что форма растягивается на 100% страницы.Поле для ввода логина, нецелесообразно делать таким. Так же, как и в Вашем 1 примере растягивать кнопку одновременно с полями ввода. Если посмотреть на форму, которую мы используем здесь для комментариев, если бы кнопка `Комментировать` располагалась под полем ввода текста, вряд ли бы она растягивалась вместе с ним по ширине. Ваш 2 пример ближе к истине, если заменить, скажем, `col-xs-12 `на `col-xs-5`. Однако мне кажется, что в Вашем коде потерян  `</div>`. Поэтому не могу понять, как это работает)

Comment: @Alex спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прочитайте [документацию по bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) подробнее, Вы путаете основы - `col-xs-N` - это колонка, которая должна быть помещена в строку `row`;
Вам необходимо сделать так:

```
<div class="container">
<form id="register-form" role="form" action="/auth/register/" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <div class="control-group required">
                <label class="control-label" for="id_username">Имя пользователя</label>
                <div class="controls">     
                    <input class="form-control" id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" class="button" value="Зарегистрироваться"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

P.S.:
Если Вам нужен `<input class="form-control" id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />`100% ширины, поставьте вместо `col-xs-3`, `col-xs-12`, [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/384n7njn/5/)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/384n7njn/)

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так: (вместо style-атрибутов вынесите все в css)

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
  <div style="width: 100%">
    <label for="ex1">col-xs-2</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" style="width: 60%">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="ex2">col-xs-3</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="ex3">col-xs-4</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="ex3" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Это код из вашего примера на w3school

Comment: хак, но работает) https://jsfiddle.net/384n7njn/2/ Спасибо